# Comparing hash table implementations

Tags: data-structures, hashtable, implementation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chained Hash Tables vs. Open-Addressed Hash Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556142/chained-hash-tables-vs-open-addressed-hash-tables)

In general I have seen two implementations of hash tables. The first is implemented as two arrays, one containing the keys, the other the values. The second has a single array, and then a linked list containing key-value objects.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of one implementation over the other? Both look equally good to me with regard to collision handling and put/get operations.

Comment: Please google this. This is a very basic topic in computer science.

Comment: @Marcin If a good answer does not yet exist on Stack Overflow, then this is a good question that deserves a good answer.

Comment: Funnily enough, it's also a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556142/chained-hash-tables-vs-open-addressed-hash-tables . I have very little sympathy for the view that we should entertain general questions on topics that are widely covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As johna says, we call The first example *open addressing*, while the latter is *chaining*.

The main drawback of *open addressing* is that by using your hashtable array for storing values, if many collisions occur, you will overflow the bucket array, and then have an expensive resizing. Also, this data structure is a little unclear.

With *chaining*, or pointers to linked lists, you will never overflow the array, though the linked lists could grow deep. This; however, is a consistent and predictable flow of data, and an easier concept.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a nice write up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  The keywords you are looking for are open addressing (sometimes called closed hashing) vs closed addressing (sometimes called open hashing).