# Which is better to handle collisions, Open addressing or Chaining?

Tags: data-structures

imagine that we have the set S containing n keys. we want to use the uniform hashing function in a table T[0,...,m-1] and m=n+2.
is it better to handle the collisions using open addressing or chaining?
I would appreciate if anyone can explain for me. thanks

Comment: open addressing/ chaining is used to handle collisions. Your question doesn't make sense because if you remove collisions(hypothetically) then you'll never need to handle them.

Comment: @RinkeshP maybe i should say wich one is better for handling the collisions?

Comment: That would be a more appropriate question.

Comment: @RinkeshP can you please explain it more?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the title as well as the content is more appropriate. One shouldn't feel the need to go through the comments to understand the context.

Comment: Might have already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556142/chained-hash-tables-vs-open-addressed-hash-tables